# Passing a Perl variable to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I need to pass a Perl variable to a JavaScript function.

```
print "<input type='radio' name='envelopeid' value='$values[0]' onclick='SetName(this.value,$values[1]);'>";
```

where **values** is an **array** variable in Perl and SetName(a,b) is the JavaScript function.

the above JavaScript function works fine when I pass one argument i.e **SetName(this.value)** but it doesn't work if I pass 2 arguments. (I have changed the JavaScript function to accept the 2 arguments accordingly)

The above function is not initiated on onclick rather it throws an error in the status bar of the browser.

What must be changed in case to pass the Perl variable $values[1] to the JavaScript function?

Comment: What is the exact error text you get? Also, please show the definition of the `SetName` function.

Comment: 'Syntax Error' is the only error message displayed in the browser.
and I am pretty sure that this error message is generated because of the $values[1] when passed to JavaScript function as an argument. can the Perl variable be passed to JavaScript function in some other way?

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to show the definition of the `SetName` function. Also add `use Data::Dumper; warn Dumper \@values;` to your Perl script immediately above the `print` line you showed, and run the CGI from the command line. That will show what the `@values` array contains; please edit the output of the warning into your question.

Comment: Finally, your browser probably has some built-in tools to help you debug JavaScript. In Firefox, for example, select Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console; this will show you more helpful error messages with line numbers so you can track down the issue in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using shell script to get the value from database and populate it for a dropdown in perl cgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812479/using-shell-script-to-get-the-value-from-database-and-populate-it-for-a-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually trying to do is pass the *value* of `$values[0]` and `$values[1]`.

To pass a value to a JS function, it needs to be created by a JS literal. JSON is a subset of JS, so a JSON encoder can be used to create this literal.

```
use JSON::XS qw( );
my $json = JSON::XS->new->allow_nonref;
my $val1_jslit = $json->encode($values[1]);
```

The JS and `$values[0]` are to be embedded in HTML, so you'll need to encode appropriately.

```
use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities );
my $val0_html       = encode_entities($values[0]);
my $val1_jslit_html = encode_entities($val1_jslit);
```

Then, you can sfely interpolate.

```
print "<input ... value='$val0_html' onclick='SetName(this.value, $val1_jslit_html);'>";
```